# Does Kedro support Checkpointing/Caching of Results?

Tags: kedro

Let's say we have multiple long running pipeline nodes.
It seems quite straight forward to checkpoint or cache the intermediate results, so when nodes after a checkpoint are changed or added only these nodes must be executed again.

Does Kedro provide functionality to make sure, that when I run the pipeline only those steps are 
executed that have changed?
Also the reverse, is there a way to make sure, that all steps that have changed are executed?

Let's say a pipeline producing some intermediate result changed, will it be executed, when i execute a pipeline depending on the output of the first?

**TL;DR:** Does Kedro have `makefile`-like tracking of what needs to be done and what not?

I think my question is similar to [issue #341](https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro/issues/341), but I do not require support of cyclic graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [IncrementalDataSet](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.IncrementalDataSet.html) alongside the [partitioned dataset](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_user_guide/08_advanced_io.html#partitioned-dataset) documentation, specifically the section on [incremental loads with the incremental dataset](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_user_guide/08_advanced_io.html#incremental-loads-with-incrementaldataset) which has a notion of "checkpointing", although checkpointing is a manual step and not automated like `makefile`.